Pallet Assets. Balances.InsufficientBalance
Trying to create an asset via the Polkadot apps interface, but encountering the error: balances.InsufficientBalance. Attempting to create the asset with a sudo account. There are sufficient funds in the account. What could be the problem?
This is my pallet assets configuration.
pub const MILLI_TOKEN: Balance = 1_000_000_000_000_000;
pub const TOKEN: Balance = 1000 * MILLI_TOKEN;
parameter_types! {
    pub const AssetDeposit: Balance = 100 * TOKEN;
    pub const ApprovalDeposit: Balance = TOKEN;
    pub const StringLimit: u32 = 50;
    pub const MetadataDepositBase: Balance = 10 * TOKEN;
    pub const MetadataDepositPerByte: Balance = TOKEN;
}
impl pallet_assets::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type Balance = u128;
    type AssetId = u32;
    type AssetIdParameter = codec::Compact<u32>;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type CreateOrigin = AsEnsureOriginWithArg<EnsureSigned<AccountId>>;
    type ForceOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type AssetDeposit = AssetDeposit;
    type AssetAccountDeposit = ConstU128<TOKEN>;
    type MetadataDepositBase = MetadataDepositBase;
    type MetadataDepositPerByte = MetadataDepositPerByte;
    type ApprovalDeposit = ApprovalDeposit;
    type StringLimit = StringLimit;
    type Freezer = ();
    type Extra = ();
    type CallbackHandle = ();
    type WeightInfo = pallet_assets::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type RemoveItemsLimit = ConstU32<1000>;
    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    type BenchmarkHelper = ();
}


Balance
ROOT (EXTENSION)5FCLQ......qNAAkTebD

transferable - 11.0101 MUNIT  
reserved - 0.4819 UNIT 
transactions - 76


but
system.account: FrameSystemAccountInfo
{
  nonce: 76
  consumers: 1
  providers: 1
  sufficients: 0
  data: {
    free: 11,010,162,781,148,209,528
    reserved: 481,985,000,000
    frozen: 0
    flags: 170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,728
  }
}


balances.account: PalletBalancesAccountData
{
  free: 0
  reserved: 0
  frozen: 0
  flags: 170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,728
}


in lib.rs this
// Unit = the base number of indivisible units for balances
pub const UNIT: Balance = 1_000_000_000_000;
pub const MILLI_UNIT: Balance = UNIT / 1_000;
pub const MICRO_UNIT: Balance = MILLI_UNIT / 1_000;

/// Existential deposit.
pub const EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT: Balance = 1;

in chain_spec.rs this
pub fn production_config() -> Result<ChainSpec, String> {

        let mut props = Properties::new();
        props.insert("tokenSymbol".to_string(), json!("UNIT"));
        props.insert("tokenDecimals".to_string(), json!(12));
....



Which call are you attempting to send? What is the decimal precision of your native token?

@AurevoirXavier updated body.

Assets.create in Extrinsics
or Create asset using just interface polkadot apps.

Actually problem was here
pub const MILLI_TOKEN: Balance = 1_000_000_000_000_000;
I replaced with
pub const MILLI_TOKEN: Balance = 1_000_000_000;
which is absolutely make sense.
